# How to achieve hand drawn look in Visio diagrams?

Tags: prototype, visio

I want to make a prototype of a website. Is there any visio stencil which gives a hand drawn look to the prototype? I found one such template with few shapes, but these are not enough to easily create a prototype:

http://www.visguy.com/2008/08/20/indexed-shapes-for-that-hand-drawn-look/

Comment: If you want to acheive a hand drawn look, why don't you hand draw it?

Answer (score 6):

You should check out [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) - excellent!

Answer (score 3):

I've built a visio stencil set of 'hand-drawn' control shapes, mainly for winforms apps, but also for web apps have a forms feel (text boxes, combos, checkboxes, lists, trees etc). I plan for more shapes in the future, feel free to send requests via github.

https://github.com/ICornwell/Visio.Handdrawn.Wireframes

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote? I was only trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

looks good, but I dont think I cannot justify the purchase to my employer. Visio comes with MSDN subscription, so a template for that would be nice

Comment: Not an endorsement, but if you looked at the web page you would see that there are many ways to get it for free, including just being willing to demo it to 15 people.

Comment: So they'll pay thousands of dollars for MSDN but not $80 for a needed tool? I totally understand. Been there before. Does it have to be Visio? If you had a similar tool for free would that work?

Answer (score -1):

Pencil, Paper, Scissors and Pritt-Stick and Scanner.

Is this really what you should be spending your employer's money doing?

Comment: Pencil and paper isn't always the most effective solution when you need to move things around.

Comment: Good point. Have edited to add other modern editing tools. ;)

Answer (score -1):

your best bet is balsamiq, it is the best visual way to get your ideas out there